# how to process a xml node text up to the first subnode and after the last one?

Tags: xml, delphi, omnixml

```
<p> Normal text <b> bolded </b> finish normal text </p>
```

Im processing that xml (example reduced) with OmniXML (but I believe the solution will apply to other XML parsers). Im traversing the xml and everytime I process a p or b tag I change some font settings etc.

The problem is that when I have a Node var pointing to the p tag and I do

> Node.TextNode

it returns "Normal text bolded finish normal text" the complete text, but I want to return only the part up to the first  tag (and also latter the last part); This way when y process the  tag thereafter I can change the font settings, and print the bolded text..

How I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uses
  OmniXML,
  OmniXMLUtils;

procedure ProcessNode(const node: IXMLNode; nodeText: TStrings);

  procedure CollectNodes(const node: IXMLNode; const nodeList: IXMLNodeList);
  var
    childNode: IXMLNode;
    iChild   : integer;
  begin
    for iChild := 0 to node.ChildNodes.Length-1 do begin
      childNode := node.ChildNodes.Item[iChild];
      if childNode.NodeType = TEXT_NODE then
        nodeText.Add(childNode.NodeValue)
      else if childNode.NodeType = ELEMENT_NODE then begin
        nodeText.Add(childNode.NodeName);
        CollectNodes(childNode, nodeList);
        nodeText.Add('/' + childNode.NodeName);
      end;
    end;
  end; { CollectNodes }

var
  childNode: IXMLNode;
  nodeList : IXMLNodeList;
begin
  nodeList := TXMLNodeList.Create;
  CollectNodes(node, nodeList);
end; { ProcessNode }

procedure TForm39.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  xml: IXMLDocument;
  nodeText: TStringList;
begin
  xml := CreateXMLDoc;
  if XMLLoadFromString(xml, '<test><p> Normal text <b> bolded </b> finish normal text </p></test>') then begin
    nodeText := TStringList.Create;
    try
      ProcessNode(xml.SelectSingleNode('test'), nodeText);
    finally FreeAndNil(nodeText); end;
  end;
end;
```

Will give you:

> ```
> p
>  Normal text
> b
>  bolded
> /b
>  finish normal text
> /p
> ```

Comment: The problem was I didnt know that "free text" was actually a child node (of type TEXT_NODE) and also I was using NodeText instead of NodeValue, all clear now.. thanks